# how to calculate CRC for modbus 16 bit

Tags: c, embedded-linux, crc, modbus, crc16

How to calculate MODBUS CRC(16bit) for 1 byte of data in C? I have referred some codes but didn't understand properly. user wants to give polynomial and data at run time. Can anybody help me out with some code?  I have tried this below code by referring the most below example, but I'm stuck in between.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){

string msg;
string crc;
string encoded="";
printf("enter msg: ");
scanf("%s", &msg);
printf("enter the polynomial:");
scanf("%s", &crc);
int m=strlen(msg);
int n = strlen(crc);
//encoded += msg;
for(int i=1;i<=n-1;i++)
```

after this what to do?

I have referred the below code.
here I have 2 doubts.

what actually these line(inside main() indicates? ---->     uint8_t str[] = "123456789";
                                                  ---->     crc = crc16_update(crc, str[8-i]);
                                                  ---->     and why 2 times for loop is running inside main() and why 2 times the polynomial is initiated?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
uint16_t crc16_update(uint16_t crc, uint8_t a) {
    int i;

    crc ^= (uint16_t)a;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        if (crc & 1)
            crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0xA001;
        else
            crc = (crc >> 1);
    }

    return crc;
}

int main(void) {
    uint16_t crc;
    int i;
    uint8_t str[] = "123456789";

    crc = 0xFFFF;
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        crc = crc16_update(crc, str[i]);
    printf("%X\n", (int)crc);

    crc = 0xFFFF;
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        crc = crc16_update(crc, str[8-i]);
    printf("%X\n", (int)crc);

}
```

Comment: If you use this [online crc calculator](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html), click on CRC16, then select CRC16_MODBUS, it matches the first loop. I don't know what the purpose of the second loop is, since it's just reversing the data. Is there a case where a message bytes are sent in reverse order? (Note - the bits of each byte are sent in reverse order, and this is taken into account in the first loop.)

Comment: thanks @rcgldr .can you please tell me what's the purpose of this line? why str array is filled with 1..9? uint8_t str[] = "123456789";

Comment: The 9 character string "123456789" became a standard to use as data for CRC algorithm verification (so you can compare your CRC implementation to known working implementations, with a relatively short string). I don't know the history behind the choice to use that string.